# EMMA report without stopping tomcat service?

Tags: emma

How to get the Coverage.ec file in ECL EMMA without stopping the tomcat service??

Answer (score 1):

Got the Answer from this site:

sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=336859

A new processor, CtlProcessor (used by a new 'emma ctl' command line
    tool and a new  ANT task) can communicate with a JVM running
    EMMA-instrumented classes via a TCP socket. On each invocation, the
    processor dispatches a series of control commands such as
    'coverage.get', 'coverage.dump', and 'coverage.reset', for example:

```
  <emma>
    <ctl connect="localhost:47653" >
      <command name="coverage.get" args="mycoverage.ec" />
      <command>coverage.reset</command> <!-- alternate command syntax -->
    </ctl>
  </emma>
or
  java -cp ... emma ctl -connect localhost:47653 \
                        -command coverage.get,mycoverage.ec \
                        -command coverage.reset
```